# zend framewok 2.2.4 installation error show openssl extension

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

zend framework 2.2.4 installation time this error show

D:\xampp\htdocs\ztest>php composer.phar install Loading composer repositories with package information Installing dependencies (including require-dev) - Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.4)

[RuntimeException] You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-p lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver bose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]

Comment: if you are using windows .. you enable that `php.ini`, I did that and works fine

Comment: if not find openssl extension how to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please comment the line on php.ini

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

if you do not have this just add this line and download the dll file from here
http://originaldll.com/file/php_openssl.dll/29889.html

this will help you.